# Detect sleep date in background on MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, sleep, detect

I have a problem about detecting sleep date and saving it. The thing is I want to run a counter, when you open the app it always count how much time passed and based on that calculates something. The thing is I want to stop counting if the computer is going to sleep. Is there any way to do this in background if the actual desktop app is not running?

I have tried NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification, but its not called if the app is not running, I also tried to do this in a menu bar app if its only an Agent its also not called, maybe its not possible to do.

Comment: I am getting NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification in menubar app.

Comment: What do you mean getting? is it working for you? I tried to save the Date but nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to improve your question by showing us some code, so that we can help you with what you are doing wrong. I have a background app without a menu bar and I do get these notifications. And yes, you will ONLY get this notification if your app is running. What I usually do I create a background-only app to register those notifications, which I will pass to the main app, via a file or an Apple Event.

Comment: In `applicationDidFinishLaunching` I used 
`nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.receiveSleepNote),
                       name: NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification, object: nil)`

In this function I simply try to save the Date:
`defaults.set(Date(), forKey: "sleepDate")`

The menu bar app is running, my goal is when I open the desktop app I want to see that sleepDate, but it always drops nil.

Comment: Please add this information to your question. Moreover please show us the code with the function you use as a selector. Most probably, you are not using the selector with the right signature.